# Why does my code not render if I use a simple res.render("filename", data)?

Tags: node.js, undefined, ejs

I am trying to render EJS files with data I grabbed from MongoDB.  This code should work:

```
col.insertOne(post)
    .then(docs => {
        res.render("input", {
            post: post
        });
    })
```

However, it doesn't, throwing a "docs is not defined" error.
If I write an if-else function, though, everything works peachy-keen and my EJS file appears with all the correct data.

```js
col.insertOne(post)
    .then(docs => {
        if (docs) {
            res.render("input", {
                post: post
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Docs is undefined');
        }
    })
```

Why is this?

Comment: can you cosole.log(docs) and comment everything else inside .then()

Comment: likely your code ran twice, the first with a null docs

Comment: @user9879287 I have done that, docs produces a huge MongoDB array/object/whatever that I don't understand.  Any other ideas?